# NEO4J local server does not start

Tags: linux, neo4j, localhost

I am running Linux in VirtualBox and am having an issue that I did not encounter on my machine with Linux as the primary OS.

When launching the neo4j service through `sudo ./neo4j start` in `/opt/neo4j-community-2.3.1/bin` I get a timeout with the message `Failed to start within 120 seconds. Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs`

my log from `/opt/neo4j-community-2.3.1/data/graph.db/messages.log` says:

http://pastebin.com/wUA715QQ

and `data/log/console.log` says:

```
    2016-01-06 02:07:03.404+0100 INFO  Successfully started database
2016-01-06 02:07:03.603+0100 INFO  Successfully stopped database
2016-01-06 02:07:03.604+0100 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2016-01-06 02:07:03.608+0100 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.security.auth.FileUserRepository@9ab182' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.security.auth.FileUserRepository@9ab182' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.security.auth.FileUserRepository@9ab182' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.security.auth.FileUserRepository@9ab182' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/neo4j-community-2.3.1/data/dbms/auth
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
        at org.neo4j.server.security.auth.FileUserRepository.loadUsersFromFile(FileUserRepository.java:208)
        at org.neo4j.server.security.auth.FileUserRepository.start(FileUserRepository.java:73)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 5 more
```

Any idea why the server won't start?

Comment: can you also check `data/log/console.log` ?

Comment: @MichaelHunger yes, updated my question with it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions on /opt/neo4j-community-2.3.1/data/dbms/auth

See the line that says:
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/neo4j-community-2.3.1/data/dbms/auth

Comment: There is onyl 1 lien in that file. It says: `neo4j:SHA-256,57DCF4E3350286BF320EB63789389F16BC1A517536E54DDD3E5336CEDE0C686C,88455AAB2DC6930357693A46D1E61F09:password_change_required`